# Plotting a pandas Series using dates and values too squished

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a simple pandas Series object, its something like this:

```
2018-01-01   10  
2018-01-02   90  
2018-01-03   79  
...  
2020-01-01   9  
2020-01-02   72  
2020-01-03   65
```

It includes only the first month of each year, so it only contains the month January and all its values through the days.

When i try to plot it

```
# suppose the name of the series is dates_and_values
dates_and_values.plot()
```

It returns a plot like this (made using my current data)

[image]

It is clearly plotting by year and then the month, so it looks pretty squished and small, since i don't have any other months except January, is there a way to plot it by the year and day so it outputs a better plot to observe the days.

Comment: Have you tried converting your index to a string instead of a datetime, then plotting? This may prevent it from inferring dates between the data

Comment: [Distribute different years into different subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)? [Pandas has incorporated this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html) with the keyword `subplots`.

Answer (score 0):

- the x-axis is the index of the dataframe
- dates are a continuous series, x-axis is continuous
- change index to be a string of values, means it it no longer continuous and **squishes** your graph
- have generated some sample data that only has January to demonstrate

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cf = pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask="Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat", 
                                          holidays=[d for d in pd.date_range("01-jan-1990",periods=365*50, freq="D") 
                                                    if d.month!=1])

d = pd.date_range("01-jan-2015", periods=200, freq=cf)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Values":np.random.randint(20,70,len(d))}, index=d)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=[14,6])


df.set_index(df.index.strftime("%Y %d")).plot(ax=ax[0])
df.plot(ax=ax[1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you convert the series to a dataframe and then pivot it to get one column for each year. This lets you plot the data for each year with a separate line, either in the same plot using different colors or in subplots. Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np   # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd  # v 1.2.3

# Create sample series
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=123)  # random number generator
dt = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2020-01-31', freq='D')
dt_jan = dt[dt.month == 1]
series = pd.Series(rng.integers(20, 90, size=dt_jan.size), index=dt_jan)

# Convert series to dataframe and pivot it
df_raw = series.to_frame()
df_pivot = df_raw.pivot_table(index=df_raw.index.day, columns=df_raw.index.year)
df = df_pivot.droplevel(axis=1, level=0)
df.head()
```

[image: df]

```py
# Plot all years together in different colors
ax = df.plot(figsize=(10,4))
ax.set_xlim(1, 31)
ax.legend(frameon=False, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.65))
ax.set_xlabel('January', labelpad=10, size=12)
for spine in ['top', 'right']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
```

[image: df_plot]

```py
# Plot years separately
axs = df.plot(subplots=True, color='tab:blue', sharey=True,
              figsize=(10,8), legend=None)
for ax in axs:
    ax.set_xlim(1, 31)
    ax.grid(axis='x', alpha=0.3)
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ax.text(28.75, 80, *labels, size=14)
    if ax.is_last_row():
        ax.set_xlabel('January', labelpad=10, size=12)
ax.figure.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
```

[image: df_subplots]